# EJS, using only with HTML

Tags: html, ejs

I have already used ejs with my node js projects. What I want to know is, is it possible to use ejs only with html. (without node).

Comment: Have you opened up your IDE and tried...? That might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS is built in JavaScript.  It doesn't require Node.js, just a JavaScript environemtn.

HTML is a markup language... not something you can program in.  But, of course you can insert a `<script>` tag for your JavaScript in HTML, and run EJS and any other JavaScript you want.